# Weighted Letter Generator

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, random, hash

I am working on a programme that creates jumbled up groups of letters, for this, I am creating 2 weighted letter generators, one for consonants, one for vowels.

Currently I have a weighted number generator using hashes for the weighting, and I can call the letter picking function with the number of letters I want it to return (eg. pick_vowel(3))

```
def pick_vowel(x)
  vowels = { A: 15, E: 21, I: 13, O: 13, U: 5 }
  v_choice = []
  vowels.map {|letter, number| number.times {v_choice << letter}}
  x.times {print v_choice.shuffle!.pop}
end
```

The idea is then to pass the resulting string to a functions which gives all possible combinations of a certain length, using the code below:

```
def solver(vowel)
  puts (2..9).flat_map{|size| board.combination(size).map(&:join)}
end
```

but when I pass the string I get the following error message (in this case x = 6):

```
in `block in solver': undefined method `combination' for 6:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

I want to convert the output string to an array, but as far as I can tell there is an integer which appears in the output string, so the array method won't apply to it.

How do I prevent my output from containing an integer at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose

```
vowels = { A: 5, E: 8, I: 4, O: 7, U: 3, Y: 1 }
```

I understand the values of this hash are the weights of drawing the associated keys. You first construct (in a different way):

```
v_choice = vowels.flat_map { |k,v| [k]*v }
  #=> [:A, :A, :A, :A, :A,
  #    :E, :E, :E, :E, :E, :E, :E, :E,
  #    :I, :I, :I, :I,
  #    :O, :O, :O, :O, :O, :O, :O,
  #    :U, :U, :U,
  #    :Y]
```

Next you perform

```
x.times {print v_choice.shuffle!.pop}
```

Suppose the first shuffle produces the following:

```
v_choice
  #=> [:O, :O, :E, :U, :U, :O, :A, :E, :E, :E, :U, :I, :A, :I,
  #    :E, :A, :O, :O, :E, :E, :O, :A, :I, :A, :O, :E, :I, :Y]
```

and then

```
print v_choice.pop
```

prints `"Y"`, and removes the only `:Y` from `v_choice`. Therefore, (with probability 1) `:Y` will be randomly drawn no more, contradicting the fact that it has a positive weight.

If the values of `vowels` are not weights, but numbers in a finite collection of vowels one could simplify greatly. After computing `v_choice`, one need only write

```
puts v_choice.sample(x).join
  # EOOYEIIEOI
```

or

```
puts v_choice.shuffle[0,x].join
  # EOOUOEEIAE
```

Now let's assume that the values of `vowels` are indeed weights. Then we need only write

```
x = 10
x.times { print v_choice.sample }
# OAEYEUAOAO
```

If the values of `vowels` are large, `v_choice` is correspondingly large. That would affect memory requirements but not execution speed. If the memory requirement were expensive (unlikely, perhaps), one could  do the following.

```
tot_wts = vowels.values.sum.to_f
  #=> 28.0
cum = 0
cum_dist = vowels.map do |v,wt|
  cum_wt = cum + wt/tot_wts
  cum = cum_wt
  [v, cum_wt]
end
  #=> [[:A, 0.17857142857142858],
  #    [:E, 0.4642857142857143],
  #    [:I, 0.6071428571428572],
  #    [:O, 0.8571428571428572],
  #    [:U, 0.9642857142857143],
  #    [:Y, 1.0]]
```

In case of round-off error we might set

```
cum_dist[-1][-1] = 1.0
```

We can then produce the weighted sample thusly.

```
x = 10
x.times do
  rn = rand
  print cum_dist.find { |_,cum| rn < cum }.first
end
# EAAOOEEIOA
```

Note we cannot write

```
print cum_dist.find { |_,cum| rand < cum }.first
```

because the value returned by `rand` would be constantly changing within `find`'s block.

This technique, the so-called "inverse transform method", is commonly used to generate discrete random variates in simulation models.

Comment: The values of vowels were a finite set of numbers, so your solution provided me with a string I can then manipulate in the remainder of the code!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
x.times {print v_choice.shuffle!.pop}
```

The above prints the value `x` times and **returns the value of `x`**. That‘s how `Integer#times` works.

Instead you need:

```
x.times.map { v_choice.shuffle!.pop }
```

Or, better,

```
v_choice.shuffle!.pop(x)
```

since `Array#pop` accepts the argument.

Comment: This really helped in cleaning up the code, but the output ended up providing the key values, eg:

'[:A,:E,:O]'

So I would then need to exchange the keys to strings